# How to get `Type` of subclass from base class

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I have an abstract base class where I would like to implement a method that would retrieve an attribute property of the inheriting class. Something like this...

```
public abstract class MongoEntityBase : IMongoEntity {

    public virtual object GetAttributeValue<T>(string propertyName) where T : Attribute {
        var attribute = (T)typeof(this).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T));
        return attribute != null ? attribute.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(attribute, null) : null;
    }
}
```

And Implemented like so...

```
[MongoDatabaseName("robotdog")]
[MongoCollectionName("users")]
public class User : MonogoEntityBase {
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Movie> movies { get; set; }
}
```

But of course with the above code the `GetCustomAttribute()` is not an available method because this isn't a concrete class.

What does `typeof(this)` in the abstract class need to change to in order to have access to the inheriting class? Or is this not good practice and should I implement the method in the inheriting class altogether?

Comment: Shouldn't `User` inherit from `MongoEntityBase`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `this.GetType()`. That will provide you with the *actual* concrete type of the instance.

So in this case:

```
public virtual object GetAttributeValue<T>(string propertyName) where T : Attribute {
    var attribute = this.GetType().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T));
    return attribute != null ? attribute.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(attribute, null) : null;
}
```

Note, that it will return the top-most class. That is, if you had:

```
public class AdministrativeUser : User
{

}

public class User : MongoEntityBase
{

}
```

Then `this.GetType()` will return `AdministrativeUser`.

---

Also, this means that you could implement the `GetAttributeValue` method outside of the `abstract` base class. You wouldn't require implementers to inherit from `MongoEntityBase`.

```
public static class MongoEntityHelper
{
    public static object GetAttributeValue<T>(IMongoEntity entity, string propertyName) where T : Attribute 
    {
        var attribute = (T)entity.GetType().GetCustomAttribute(typeof(T));
        return attribute != null ? attribute.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(attribute, null) : null;
    }
}
```

(could also implement it as an extension method if you wish to)

Answer (score 7):

`typeof(this)` won't compile.

What you're searching for is `this.GetType()`.